# How to fetch state corresponding to a list of zipcode in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, business-intelligence

My excel data contains zip code data but there is no state details.

Is there any way in excel to auto populate state based on corresponding zip code.

Please note: A state can many zip codes but not vice -versa.

Comment: re: *'A state can many zip codes but not vice -versa'*. That's where you would be wrong. There are many instances of standard zip codes (non-zip+4) that straddle US state lines. You will need a cross-reference table. Start with the US postal service; they have some information available for free download.

Comment: Let me try to put this in another way... In my excel sheet, I already had a column named " Zipcode" which contains zipcode data.                        Now, I need to add another  column named "State" and what I expect excel to do is --- based on some formulas|APIs|VBAs, it should fetch state for each corresponding zipcode. Is this requirement can be achieved in excel ?

Comment: Let me try to put this in another way... see [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). Also available in [Our 10 most popular functions](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb).

Comment: As Jeeped said - you'll need a list of zip codes and states so you can do a look up.  There's plenty of sites offering free lists - http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/ or http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/ for example.  Then using the download from the first link as an example you can use a VLOOKUP function - =VLOOKUP(45502,B1:E81832,4,FALSE) would return OH as the state.  The list doesn't appear to have any codes that span state lines, but there's plenty that span different cities.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the first of the links kindly provided by @Darren Bartrup-Cook I think you may not need a table_array of over 42,522 entries (83 may be sufficient) when applying VLOOKUP's inexact matching:

```
Min State
501 NY
601 PR
801 VI
901 PR
1001    MA
2801    RI
3031    NH
3901    ME
5001    VT
5501    MA
5601    VT
6001    CT
6390    NY
6401    CT
7001    NJ
9001    AE
10001   NY
15001   PA
19701   DE
20001   DC
20101   VA
20201   DC
20588   MD
20590   DC
20598   VA
20599   DC
20601   MD
22003   VA
24701   WV
27006   NC
29001   SC
30002   GA
32003   FL
34001   AA
34101   FL
35004   AL
37010   TN
38601   MS
39813   GA
40003   KY
43001   OH
46001   IN
48001   MI
50001   IA
53001   WI
55001   MN
56901   DC
57001   SD
58001   ND
59001   MT
60001   IL
63001   MO
66002   KS
68001   NE
70001   LA
71601   AR
73001   OK
73301   TX
73401   OK
75001   TX
80001   CO
82001   WY
83201   ID
83414   WY
83415   ID
84001   UT
85001   AZ
87001   NM
88510   TX
88901   NV
90001   CA
96201   AP
96701   HI
96799   AS
96801   HI
96910   GU
96939   PW
96941   FM
96950   MP
96960   MH
97001   OR
98001   WA
99501   AK
```

Assuming the above 2-column array is named `ZipState` and of workbook scope in the same workbook as the codes you wish to look up and the codes are in a column starting in F1, this formula may serve:

```
=VLOOKUP(F1,ZipState,2)
```

copied down to suit. Normally not at all a good idea, the fourth [optional] parameter for [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) i.e. *range_lookup* is not included so the default applies and approximate matches are found as well as exact ones. Since the list is sorted ascending a search for `901` will return `PR` (an exact match) but so will `1000`.

There are more entries than 'States' because, although ZIP codes are mostly assigned in blocks, there are inevitably exceptions, for example `NY` is mostly `10001` to `14925` but also `501` and `544` (Holtsville) and `6390` (Fishers Island). Each 'block' (even if only a single ZIP code) for each 'State' has to be a separate entry since it is the lower limit of each 'block' that is being used to represent each entire 'block'.

Two points to note are:

1. Not all ZIP codes in the range `501` to `99950` (both inclusive) are valid and the above approach may assign a 'State' to an invalid code. For example, there is no `530` but the above approach would nevertheless return `NY`.
2. I extracted the abbreviated version and might have not assigned the 'blocks' correctly.

Depending upon the number of ZIP codes to be looked up and how critical the 'State' information is further checking may be advisable.